# Difference between instantiating something from the class and from the companion object

Tags: scala, scalacheck, property-based-testing

I am reading and working on the exercises on the book Funcional Programming in Scala. In the chapter about property testing, one exercise ask to implement `def listOf[A](g: Gen[A]): SGen[List[A]]`, here is the relevant code:

```
case class Gen[+A](sample: State[RNG, A]) {

  def flatMap[B](f: A ⇒ Gen[B]): Gen[B] =
    Gen(sample.flatMap(f(_) sample))

  /* A method alias for the function we wrote earlier. */
  def listOfN(size: Int): Gen[List[A]] =
    Gen.listOfN(size, this)

  def listOfN(size: Gen[Int]): Gen[List[A]] =
    size flatMap (Gen listOfN (_, this))
}

object Gen {
  def listOfN[A](n: Int, g: Gen[A]): Gen[List[A]] =
    Gen(State.sequence(List.fill(n)(g.sample)))

  def listOf[A](g: Gen[A]): SGen[List[A]] =
  //  SGen { n ⇒ g.listOfN(n) }
  //  SGen{listOfN(_, g)}
}

case class SGen[+A](forSize: Int ⇒ Gen[A])
```

As you can see, `listOf[A](g: Gen[A]): SGen[List[A]]` is implemented in two ways, the second one is the one I thought, and the first one is the solution provided by the book.

My question is, is there any difference between creating that `SGen` via the companion object and creating it using the `listOfN` method on the generator `g`? I suppose as long as both implementations ends up using `g` to generate the values, there is little difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no practical difference in this example. You can see from the implementation that `Gen.listOfN(size: Int)` is just calling the companion object implementation. One of the advantages of the method alias is that you could use simpler syntax in the companion object like this:

```
object Gen {
    ...
    def listOf[A](g: Gen[A]): SGen[List[A]] =
        SGen(g.listOfN)
}
```

Having these different syntax options can make a bigger impact on clarity when users make larger compositions.

Comment: Thanks, and could it be any example in which there is a significant different?